# The Animate Package timeline option does not work

Tags: animate, timeline

I have written a very simple example to start applying the timeline option of the animate package in my presentations. The example is very much like the one in the manual "The Animate Package" by Alexander Grahn, in the 15th of April of 2016 version, page 16:

This is the example (in the tex file "Working_Example_Article.tex"):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{filecontents}{sample.tln} 
::0X0 %first frame repeated until the end 
::1
::2
::3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\animategraphics[
label=sample,
scale=0.35,
loop,
timeline=sample.tln
]{4}{Sample_}{1}{4}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

In the working directory, I have the files Sample_1.png, Sample_2.png, Sample_3.png, Sample_4.png (in fact, I have from 1 to 100). When I try to compile this code, by using the standard:

```
~$ pdflatex Working_Example_Article
```

I am unable to generate the corresponding pdf because compilation ends at:

```
(./Working_Example_Article.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
<building timeline a0 from file `sample.tln':
! Argument of \_pbs_reftonum:w has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.22     ...]{4}{Sample_}{1}{4}
                               ^^M
```

The thing is worrisome and weird because all I have done is building a simplified version of the first example of the manual I mentioned above. Any help? I will very much appreciate it!!!

Comment: Oops, the second report about mal-function of the `timeline` option today ...

Comment: As suggested [a couple of hours earlier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366994/animate-option-timeline-doesnt-seem-to-work#comment904885_366994), add `\usepackage{filecontents}` to the preamble and try again.

Comment: Also I compiled an example using the required sty-files at the current CTAN versions on [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59022c663d83f3b45313da36).

Comment: Problem solved. The kind of error I found was caused by TeXLive 2015, which seems to be outdated. For the `animate package` to work wonderfully, at least TeXLive 2016 is required. After installing TeXLive 2016, the problem vanished. Thank you AlexG for your support and assistance. – David Alonso

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the reported problem occurs only with old package versions.

Comment: What does it mean? When a question is declared off topic, can it be still seen by all users in the community?