# Compilation in DVI with driver 'dvisvgm' is not successful in MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, animations, animate, dvisvgm

*Environment*:

> Windows 10 (x64);
>   MiKTeX 2.9.7206-x64, GPL Ghostscript 9.25 (2018-09-13)
>   Shared TeX installation;
>   'animate' package 2019/08/22;
>  
>   'dvisvgm' 2.6.3 (utility from MiKTeX);
>   2017/06/20 v1.0b dvisvgm graphics driver for latex (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\dvisvgm.def)

---

I'm trying to compile an example from manual of [Alexander Grahn](https://gitlab.com/agrahn/animate) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{intcalc} %defines \intcalcMod for Modulo computation
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{{files/}}

\newcounter{scarab}
\setcounter{scarab}{0}
\newcounter{blueline}
\setcounter{blueline}{101}
\newcounter{grayline}
\setcounter{grayline}{202}
%write timeline file
\newwrite\TimeLineFile
\immediate\openout\TimeLineFile=scarab.tln
\whiledo{\thescarab<101}{
\ifthenelse{\intcalcMod{\thescarab}{2}=0}{
%a gray line is added to every 2nd frame
\immediate\write\TimeLineFile{%
::\thegrayline x0;253;\thescarab x0,\theblueline}
\stepcounter{grayline}
}{
\immediate\write\TimeLineFile{%
::;253;\thescarab x0,\theblueline}
}
\stepcounter{scarab}
\stepcounter{blueline}
}
\immediate\closeout\TimeLineFile
%\DeclareGraphicsRule{.mps}{eps}{*}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\animategraphics[width=0.8\linewidth,
autoplay,controls,loop,timeline=scarab.tln]{12}{scarab_}{0}{253}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This source file can be converted to a PDF file without option '**dvisvgm**' by any way, i.e. 'pdflatex' or 'latex' ---> 'dvips' ---> 'ps2pdf'. Result is Ok. But after adding this option (in '\documentclass[12pt,**dvisvgm**]{article}') the building DVI file becomes impossible (command line: latex *file*.tex):

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .mps.

l.35 ...ine=scarab.tln]{12}{scarab_}{0}{253}
```

If I insert

```
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.mps}{eps}{*}{}
```

Compilation aborted with:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pbs_pdflastann: ->\g_pbs_pdflastann_tl 

l.35 ...ine=scarab.tln]{12}{scarab_alter_}{0}{253}
```

Without option 'divsvgm' the utility **dvisvgm** creates only single svg file from DVI. 
It says [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367057/the-animate-package-timeline-option-does-not-work) that a similar problem has been solved by updating the TeXLive installation.
I wonder if someone can specify what needs to be updated in MiKTeX to get rid of this error.

P.S.

- [File List](https://ozrio.com/archive/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/scarab_animate_with_controls_ok.log) in case without [12pt,dvisvgm]
- [File List](https://ozrio.com/archive/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/scarab_animate_with_controls.log) in case with [12pt,dvisvgm]

File list of successful compilation, with class option `dvisvgm` (AlexG):

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
 animate.sty    2019/08/20 PDF & SVG animations from files and inline graphics
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
   ifpdf.sty    2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2019/10/24 v1.0a TeX engine tests
ifluatex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
 ifxetex.sty    2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
 ifdraft.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Detect class options draft and final (HO)
    calc.sty    2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
graphics.sty    2019/10/08 v1.3c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
 dvisvgm.def    2017/06/20 v1.0b dvisvgm graphics driver for latex
zref-abspage.sty    2018/11/21 v2.27 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2018/11/21 v2.27 Module base for zref (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2019/07/25 v0.30 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
 pdfbase.sty    2019/11/04 v0.35 driver independent access to low-level PDF fea
tures
   expl3.sty    2019-10-28 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2019-10-28 L3 programming layer 
l3deprecation.def    2019-04-06 v L3 Deprecated functions
l3backend-dvisvgm.def    2019-04-06 L3 backend support: dvisvgm
l3keys2e.sty    2019-10-11 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
files/scarab_0.mps
...
files/scarab_253.mps
 ***********
```

Comment: I have an error too, but not the same: `! LaTeX Error: File ifxetex.sty not found.`

Comment: @AndréC that error is unrelated just install the iftex group of packages in miktex or texlive, whichever you are using

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's what I did and I have another error on this compilation: `! Package animate Error: None of the files
(animate) scarab_0.pdf,
(animate) scarab_0.mps,
(animate) scarab_0.png,
(animate) scarab_0.jpg,
(animate) scarab_0.jpeg,
(animate) scarab_0.jp2,
(animate) scarab_0.j2k or
(animate) scarab_0.jpx,
(animate) could be found.
(animate) Wrong file type? Mis-spelled file name?`

Comment: the scarab source file is here check you have it locally https://gitlab.com/agrahn/animate/tree/master/files

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I downloaded animate on CTAN and added the `files` folder in the one where the one I am compiling is located and I still have this error.... weird.

Comment: @AndréC According to the animate manual, you need to process `scarab.mp` with `mpost --tex=latex` first. It creates the missing `.mps` files.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The compilation now works, but not the animation. There is progress. :-)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem here. With document option `dvisvgm` the `.tex` file compiles correctly and dvisvgm produces a single SVG file containing the JavaScript code required to play the animation. The animation starts when viewing the SVG file in a web browser, for example.

Comment: @Martin With `dvisvgm` 2.6.3 (TL19, Linux) and current Ghostscript-9.50, EPS inclusion doesn't work. The MWE `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{graphicx}\begin{document}\includegraphics{example-image.eps}\end{document}` produces Ghostscript warnings (`*** WARNING - you have selected SAFER, ... DELAYBIND ... WRITESYSTEMDICT ...`) an the error:  `PostScript error: invalidfileaccess in run. Operand stack: example-image.eps  r`. I tried to build `dvisvgm-2.8` inside the TL svn sources, but compilation failed. Would you please give some hints about how to build dvisvgm?

Comment: @AlexG I'm not an expert for the TL build environment. I mainly use the TL packages coming with my Linux distro and build dvisvgm against them. Anyway, the sources of dvisvgm 2.8 contain a couple of new files and additional subfolders, so that the files `Makefile.am` in `texk/dvisvgm/dvisvgm-src` and below must be updated accordingly. They are almost identical to those coming with dvisvgm but require some tweaking. In order to fix the GS issue it's probably easier to simply apply [this patch](https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm/commit/7b93a9197b69305429183affd24fa40ee04a663a.patch).

Comment: @Martin Thanks a lot! After patching the dvisvgm-2.6.3 sources eps/mps/pdf inclusion works smoothly with the most recent Ghostscript (Library)!

Comment: @nailer Please do an update of all MikTeX packages (if not done recently), then, get the repository version of [`pdfbase.sty`](https://gitlab.com/agrahn/media9/raw/master/pdfbase.sty), since pkg `expl3`'s output driver set-up has changed recently. Run `dvisvgm --font-format=woff --exact --zoom=-1` on the itermediate DVI. [View SVG](https://agrahn.gitlab.io/svg/scarabtest.svg) Firefox is slow, use Chrom(e/ium) instead.

Comment: @AndréC Repository version of [`pdfbase.sty`](https://gitlab.com/agrahn/media9/raw/master/pdfbase.sty) is needed. View SVG [here](https://agrahn.gitlab.io/svg/scarabtest.svg). Note that Firefox is too slow, use Chrome or Chromium instead.

Comment: @AlexG Alex, thanks for the advice and your package 'anumate'!
As for the topic, I have the same version of the kernel 'expl3' as in the repository (2019-10-28)
It's the same error with your pdfbase.sty:
    '<building timeline a0 from file `"scarab.tln"':
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    \pbs_pdflastann: ->\g_pbs_pdflastann_tl

    l.35 ...ine=scarab.tln]{12}{scarab_alter_}{0}{253}'

My version GS is 9.25, If I replace mgs.exe with a GS-9.50 (gswin64c.exe), MiKTeX 2.9 returns ('repairs the installation') to the old version.

Comment: @nailer : Would you please put `\listfiles` as the very first line in the code, then run `latex` on it. Open the `*.log` file, search for `*File List*`, copy the list of files that follows and post that into  your question?

Comment: @AlexG [Log without](https://ozrio.com/archive/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/scarab_animate_with_controls_ok.log) *dvisvgm*, [log with](https://ozrio.com/archive/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/scarab_animate_with_controls.log) *dvisvgm*

Comment: @nailer Thank you. Unfortunately I cannot find the section starting with `*File List*` in the log . Did you put `\listfiles` before `\documentclass...` ? I paste mine into your question, so that you can compare with yours and find differences.

Comment: @AlexG Sorry, TeX stops logging and aborts execution when too many errors pile (100 errors). I had to modify the source. [Here](https://ozrio.com/archive/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/scarab_animate_with_controls.log) list. Many differences

Comment: @nailer From your log I can see that you are using an ancient `animate` version (2018/06/27). This is for sure not the installed (MiKTeX) one. It seems there is an old `animate.sty` hanging around in your working directory or in a subdirectory of it. Delete that one.

Comment: @AlexG Yes, now the same listing of files that you have. But the SVG extraction  is not successful:  `PostScript error: undefined in LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1--base`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100705/discussion-between-alexg-and-nailer).

Comment: **Many thanks** to ``@AlexG`` and ``@Martin`` for their help! The problem was created by the absence of a variable ``prologues`` in my old Metapost file. It's not related to MiKTeX. It was a very difficult investigation... Thnks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem it addresses was caused by using an old package version.

Comment: @AlexG I agree with your proposal. This question is not related to MiKTeX as it turned out.